# SQL querying via multiple, interrelated tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have two tables:

```
Table A:                  Table B:

SNo  Name                 SNo  Name    Std     Talent

1    Amy                  1    Amy      2      Soccer Wonderkid
2    Andy                 2    Andy     3      Street Dance Pro
3    Ben                  3    Asa      4      Kung-Fu Master
                          4    Ben      2      Nerd King
                          5    Chris    4      Hacker Overlord
```

**Query 1:** How do I select the rows in table B only for the kids who have an entry in Table A, using a single SQL statement (nested if necessary)?

**Query 2:** Silly this one, but will the response to Query 1 be accepted/processed correctly in JDBC?

Comment: Please tag your questions correctly.  What database are you really using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if key is `SNo` or `Name` so query will be

```
SELECT b.*
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableb b
ON a.name = b.name
```

or

```
SELECT b.*
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableb b
ON a.sno = b.sno
```

Comment: Key is the name, curiously :) so yes, the 2nd option was what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Query one is something like

`SELECT a.name, b.talent from a,b where a.SNo = b.SNo`

**EDIT**: [working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e38ef/1)

It could also be:

`SELECT a.name, b.talent from a,b where a.Name = b.Name`

depending on what's actually the key for both tables.

Answer to question 2: Why not? JDBC passes any query to your server and should not interfere your queries internally.

Comment: there is no connection on SNo field between 2 tables

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion What do you mean by "connection between 2 tables" - ?

Comment: i meant not connected by sno column

Comment: That's what the OP leaves unclear: What's the Primary Key? I first assumed SNo, but it could also be Name. Make an edit ...

Answer (score 0):

If `SNo` is the primary key,

```
SELECT *
FROM B
WHERE SNo IN (SELECT SNo FROM A)
```

If `Name` is the primary key,

```
SELECT *
FROM B
WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM A)
```

Answer (score 0):

select tableB.* from tableB Inner Join tableA on tableB.name = tableA.name

Here is [¨sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0291e/6)